# ActiveRecord clone record with in memory association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I have an active record model that belongs_to a user:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  ...
end
```

In my model test I have a before_all block:

```
before :all do
  @profile = build(:user)
end
```

Each test case gets a clean copy of the profile class through an accessor method, that takes a deep clone of the the object:

```
def profile
  @profile.dup
end
```

Nice and fast rather than calling the factory each time :)

However my problem is that because the profile and its associations are in memory, user_id does not exist on the profile, as such the in memory user object is not copied either.

So while `@profile.user` is an object:

```
<User id: nil, email 'test@test.com '.../>
```

`@profile.dup.user` is

```
nil
```

If I where to call `@profile.save` then magically

`@profile.dup.user` becomes:

```
<User id: 1, email 'test@test.com '...>
```

Short of overriding my private method to copy the user explicitly on to the clone is there a way to get rails to do the lifting. I.e. make the `dup` method behave the the same as if `@profile` had been persisted?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: `@profile.save` stores the profile and the user (in the database), so it is not real magic that  `@profile.user.id` is now defined as it takes over the newly created record id. Back to your question, you want to prevent that `@profile.user.id` is being updated? Or is there another problem you want to tackle? (not very clear to me)

Comment: I want @profile.dup to copy the in memory user object too